# Bootstrap table's tab nav panels have stopped working randomly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My site's table with a nav panel has stopped switching tables with the nav. I haven't done any updates recently but a visitor noticed and reported it. Any idea?

You can find the table at http://fatherandsonlending.com/#terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you didn't include the bootstrap js file in your page. Put

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

After your jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm very dumb for not seeing that was removed. Thanks!